# About executing functions immediately in JavaScript closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, closures

```js
var funcs=[];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){

  funcs[i]=function(){
    console.log(i);
    };
  }
for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
  funcs[j]();
  }
```

In this way ,I know it will alert 3 all.Because the functions were called after i was assigned to 3.

But in the below code, I can't understand why this happens.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 2000);
}
```

In my oppinion, when i was assigned to 0, the first function setTimeout would be executed before i was assigned to 1.

Am I wrong in the order of this loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: You get 3x3 for exactly the same reason. *"the first function setTimeout would be executed before i was assigned to 1."* No, all the functions are executed after the loop has terminated, at which point `i` has the value `3`. The loop doesn't wait for the timeout. And this is actually evident from the fact that you get the output of all 3 functions at *once* 2 seconds in the future. There isn't a 2 sec delay between each output.

Comment: What do you mean '3x3'? And why 'all the functions are executed after the loop has terminated'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console.log(i) will be called after the for loop finished, the for loop which because of the way `var` is function scoped. Will be 10 by the time (2000ms) it reaches the console.log statement. One way to give the expected result is using `let` instead of `var`. However you are removing some browser support with using let.

Good reading on this topic would be [getify's "You Don't Know Js" book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch3.md).

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: My question is why"console.log(i) will be called after the for loop finished"?

Comment: The for loop finishes immediately. console.log is inside a `setTimeout`, which will wait before executing. It's happening asynchronously compared to the for loop. `setTimeout` only prevents what's inside of it from executing till the timer is up. Everything outside of it will continue to operate  business as usual.

Comment: you mean it 'asynchronously' not the setTimeout wait for the loop over?

Comment: `setTimeout` will finish it's timer and execute regardless if the for loop has finished or not, however 2000ms is more than enough time for that for loop to finish incriminating `i`. The code above and before it, runs independently. This sounds like it's more an issue with asynchronous javascript and and how `setTimeout` works than function closures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `i` variable into a closure, otherwise, it will be rewritten in each loop iteration. The same occurs for the setTimeout function, you should put the `i` variable into a closure as well.

```js
var funcs=[];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){

 (function(i){ 
    funcs[i]=function(){
      console.log(i);
    };
  })(i);
}

for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
  funcs[j]();
  }
```